# Revert changes to docker container

Tags: docker

Is it possible to create a docker container, run a command inside it, then revert the changes to the container filesystem resulting from that command and run another command?

The motivation is that I wish to run a large number of short-lived programs in a consistent environment, and I'm hoping to avoid the cost of creating/destroying a separate container for each one.

I'm aware that it is possible to use `docker commit` and `docker history` to create a new container from a previous snapshot of an existing container, but with this method I'd still have to create a new container each time I want to rollback. My goal is to avoid that step by rolling back the filesystem changes for an already-running container.

From what I understand about aufs it seems this should be possible in principle, but I'm not sure whether it's supported by the docker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the 6 containers related to nixos at https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=nixos&page=1&isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&starCount=0&pullCount=0 as nixos allows you to do `rollback production` and such things.

have also a look at the 22 containers related to ubuntu snappy
https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=snappy&page=1&isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&starCount=0&pullCount=0

I am not aware of a docker way to do this.